# How Do I Get a System Update to My Laravel Admin Panel?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, laravel-8

I aim to develop a content management system through Laravel. How can I create a structure in my CMS software that will receive a system update manually or automatically, just like Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite finicky, but in a nutshell you would make a cron-job to check if a new update is available. If a new one is available then you will have to check which pieces of your stack are out of a date and create a routine to update those.

That's really it. There are many more small things around security/preventing downtime that go into it. For example, you probably want to put the site offline while making changes to the database, etc, etc..

If you want to know some in depth information, wordpress is still open source. Wordpress still uses subversion but you can find a mirror here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress

Comment: Thank you for the comment mate. I will review :)